# Unable to play radio source in html5

Tags: javascript, html

I have these couple of radio sources:

Radio 1 - http://ice3.securenetsystems.net/CKDX?playSessionID=2F01BCBA-BE9D-2A65-5B280ECE3E397AFE

Radio 2 - http://ice5.securenetsystems.net/CIRV?playSessionID=2EFE4082-EC1E-6FA0-10941E29181F671A

They both are working fine originally but when I put these sources in HTML in front of the `src`, they stop working and it's unable to play the audio.

Here's my code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
        <span class="trigger-audio fa fa-play">
             <audio src="http://ice3.securenetsystems.net/CKDX?playSessionID=2F01BCBA-BE9D-2A65-5B280ECE3E397AFE"
                volume="1.0">
            </audio>
        </span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
         <span class="trigger-audio fa fa-play">
            <audio src="http://ice5.securenetsystems.net/CIRV?playSessionID=2EFE4082-EC1E-6FA0-10941E29181F671A"
                volume="1.0">
                 </audio>
            </span>
            
<script>
const audioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger-audio')
const buttonToStopAllAudios = document.querySelector('.fa-stop')

const getAudioElementFromButton = buttonElement =>
  buttonElement.querySelector('audio')

const stopAudioFromButton = buttonElement => {
  // Pause the audio
  getAudioElementFromButton(buttonElement).pause()

  // Update element classes
  buttonElement.classList.add('fa-play')
  buttonElement.classList.remove('fa-pause')
}

const playAudioFromButton = buttonElement => {
  // Pause the audio
  getAudioElementFromButton(buttonElement).play()

  // Update element classes
  buttonElement.classList.remove('fa-play')
  buttonElement.classList.add('fa-pause')
}

audioButtons.forEach(audioButton => {
  audioButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // I get this first because I have to pause all the audios before doing anything, so I have to know it this audio was paused or not
    const audioElement = getAudioElementFromButton(audioButton)
    const audioIsPaused = audioElement.paused

    // Stop all audios before starting this one
    audioButtons.forEach(stopAudioFromButton)

    audioIsPaused
      ? playAudioFromButton(audioButton) // Play if it's paused
      : stopAudioFromButton(audioButton) // Pause if it's playing
  })
})

buttonToStopAllAudios.addEventListener('click', () => {
  audioButtons.forEach(stopAudioFromButton)
})
</script>
```

What would be the easiest way to fix this?

I'm a beginner so any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: I copied and pasted your code exactly into an HTML file and it works fine for me. Can you share some details on what browser you are testing on?

Comment: @KeeganTeetaert I'm using the latest version of chrome. And you are right! I just tested it on firefox and it's working perfectly. But now I can't understand this. I have some other URLs that are working fine with the same code on chrome. Does that make chrome a bad browser or should something be changed in my code?

Comment: @KeeganTeetaert Here are the URL's that are working: 1)https://cbc_r2_tor.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/364/451661/v1/rc.akacast.akamaistream.net/cbc_r2_tor 2)http://204.2.199.166/7/288/80873/v1/rogers.akacast.akamaistream.net/tor925

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you change IP addresses, you need to refetch the playSessionID= value from the front-end web page for the stream.